# pandas concatenating columns with repeated indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes that I want to concatenate horizontally, grouping them by the value of a column. From the [pandas.pydata website](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) they do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'B7'],
                    'D': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6', 'D7'],
                    'F': ['F2', 'F3', 'F6', 'F7']},
                   index=[2, 3, 6, 7])

df1 = 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3

df4 = 
    B   D   F
2  B2  D2  F2
3  B3  D3  F3
6  B6  D6  F6
7  B7  D7  F7

result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, join='inner')

result = 
    A   B   C   D   B   D   F
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  B2  D2  F2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  B3  D3  F3
```

This works, and I'm happy about it.
So I'm using this trick to merge 2 dataframes by the value of a certain column, basically I reindex the Dataframe with that column and then I do the concatenation.
However values in that column are repeated, so I end with dataframes with repeated indexes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 3, 3, 2])
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'B7'],
                    'D': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6', 'D7'],
                    'F': ['F2', 'F3', 'F6', 'F7']},
                   index=[2, 3, 6, 7])
df1 = 
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
3  A1  B1  C1  D1
3  A2  B2  C2  D2
2  A3  B3  C3  D3

df4 = 
    B   D   F
2  B2  D2  F2
3  B3  D3  F3
6  B6  D6  F6
7  B7  D7  F7
```

So I would expect this two dataframes to join, so I will end up with:

```
result = 
    A   B   C   D   B   D   F
3  A1  B1  C1  D1  B2  D2  F2
3  A2  B2  C2  D2  B2  D2  F2
2  A3  B3  C3  D3  B3  D3  F3
```

(Notice that the two rows with index 3 in df1 both join with the row with index 3 in df4) However this doesn't work.

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7, 5), indices imply (7, 3)
```

How can I achieve that? f I can avoid merging by index but I can specify a column it would be even better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with matching by index, default `how='inner'` should be omit:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df4, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (result)
    A B_x   C D_x B_y D_y   F
2  A3  B3  C3  D3  B2  D2  F2
3  A1  B1  C1  D1  B3  D3  F3
3  A2  B2  C2  D2  B3  D3  F3
```

It create combination of duplicated matched rows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 3, 3, 3])
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'B7'],
                    'D': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6', 'D7'],
                    'F': ['F2', 'F3', 'F6', 'F7']},
                   index=[2, 3, 3, 7])
print (df1)
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
3  A1  B1  C1  D1
3  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3

print (df4)
    B   D   F
2  B2  D2  F2
3  B3  D3  F3
3  B6  D6  F6
7  B7  D7  F7

result = pd.merge(df1, df4, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (result)
    A B_x   C D_x B_y D_y   F
3  A1  B1  C1  D1  B3  D3  F3
3  A1  B1  C1  D1  B6  D6  F6
3  A2  B2  C2  D2  B3  D3  F3
3  A2  B2  C2  D2  B6  D6  F6
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  B3  D3  F3
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  B6  D6  F6
```

Comment: Yup, works, in my case only df1 will have duplicate indexes, which have to map to the unique indexes of df4.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use `join`:

```
df1.join(df4,how='inner', lsuffix='_df1', rsuffix='_df4')
```

Output:

```
    A B_df1   C D_df1 B_df4 D_df4   F
2  A3    B3  C3    D3    B2    D2  F2
3  A1    B1  C1    D1    B3    D3  F3
3  A2    B2  C2    D2    B3    D3  F3
```